# Reiniciar Postgres no Windows

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando criar um banco de dados no Postgres, mas está dando a seguinte mensagem

```
ERROR: cannot execute CREATE DATABASE in a read-only transaction
```

Já reinstalei e nada.

Já coloquei pra off essa linha no arquivo postgresql.conf, mas não sei como reiniciar as configurações

```
default_transaction_read_only = off
```

Porque ouvir falar que é isso

Estou tentando no usuário postgres

Comment: [Acredito que isso possa ajudar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186414/error-cannot-execute-create-table-in-a-read-only-transaction)

Comment: Onde posso rodar aqueles comandos? No DOS ou no SGBD?

Comment: Acredito que no SGBD.

Comment: O psql é o shell do postgre. [Postgre docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/tutorial-accessdb.html)

Comment: Não sei por onde chegar no shell dele e no SGBD não consigo digita nada

Comment: Ele vem instalado com o postgre é só buscar no pc. Se for windows, vai estar na pasta do postegre

Comment: Tem a pasta bin e a pasta data

Comment: A pasta bin está vazia

Comment: Vixi ai complica.

Comment: Procura o PGADMIN na pasta C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin o arquivo pgAdmin3.exe (se seu postgres for 9.5 e se for de 64bits). Se não encontrar em Program Files, procura em Program Files (x86)